# Set trackball header based on x position

Tags: .net, wpf, telerik

I'm trying to set the header of a wpf telerik trackball.
What I'd like to display is "X position: 12.2", with the 12.2 based on where the trackball is currently positioned.

I'm using a SeriesProvider for generating the scatterlines. What I currently have is the seriesProvider:

```
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.SeriesProvider>
        <telerik:ChartSeriesProvider Source="{Binding LineOutputModels, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <telerik:ScatterSeriesDescriptor
                ItemsSourcePath="DataPoints"
                XValuePath="X"
                YValuePath="Y">
                <telerik:ScatterSeriesDescriptor.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="telerik:ScatterLineSeries">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{Binding Color}" />
                        <Setter Property="TrackBallInfoTemplate" Value="{StaticResource trackBallInfoTemplate}" />
                    </Style>
                </telerik:ScatterSeriesDescriptor.Style>
            </telerik:ScatterSeriesDescriptor>
       </telerik:ChartSeriesProvider>
   </telerik:RadCartesianChart.SeriesProvider>
```

What I wanted to do was something like

```
    <telerik:RadCartesianChart.TrackBallInfoStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:TrackBallInfoControl">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Trackball.XPosition}" />
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadCartesianChart.TrackBallInfoStyle>
```

But I couldn't make it work. Do I have to use code behind for this?

Comment: When you say it does not work, does it not show anything?  Do you get a binding exception in VS or anything?

Comment: Hello @RobGoodwin, what I propose in the TrackBallInfoStyle gives a binding error, saying it can't find the TrackBall in the viewmodel. I really have no idea how to point to the trackball itself from that position in XAML, it was just one of the many things I tried with no success whatsoever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data context of the `TrackBallInfoControl` is inherited from the `DataContext` of the parent `RadCartesianChart` element.

To achieve your requirement, you can assign `x:Name` to the `ChartTrackBallBehavior` and use `ElementName` binding in order to access the `Position` property of the behavior.

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart.TrackBallInfoStyle>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:TrackBallInfoControl">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding ElementName=trackBallBehavior, Path=Position.X}" />
    </Style>
</telerik:RadCartesianChart.TrackBallInfoStyle>

<telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>
    <telerik:ChartTrackBallBehavior x:Name="trackBallBehavior"/>
</telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>
```